# How to create a matrix? (Python)

Tags: python, matrix, rows

I want to create a 2x3 matrix. (2 rows, 3 columns) When I run my code, I get the matrix in parentheses, which is incorrect.

```
def fill_matrix(numrows, numcols, val):
     matrix = [[val for i in range(numrows)] for j in range(numcols)]
     return (numrows, numcols, val)
```

If I choose to create a 2x2 matrix and fill all holes with 1, I'm supposed to get this:
[[1, 1], [1, 1]]

But I get this instead:
(2, 2, 1)

Comment: `(2,2,1)` is what you return from the function so it's what you get... the `matrix` variable isn't being returned

Answer (score 5):

Your `fill_matrix` function returns the tuple `(numrows, numcols, val)`, which is why you're getting `(2,2,1)`. You're not returning the matrix at all.

You could try:

```
def fill_matrix(numrows, numcols, val):
     return [[val for i in range(numrows)] for j in range(numcols)]
```

to just return the matrix itself.

If you're working with matricies you might also consider using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and doing:

```
import numpy as np
np.ones((2,2))
```

or:

```
def fill_matrix(numrows, numcols, val):
    return np.ones((numrows, numcols)) * val
```

Comment: Ahhh just return matrix was the problem for me. Thanks!